# How do I extract text from an attribute value in javascript/jquery using regex?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a number of name attributes that look like this:

```
name='[n][somevariablename]'
```

Where 'n' is an integer >= 0

I need to extract the 'somevariablename' from the name attr value and store it in a variable.
I realize I can use instr and manually extract this, but I thought I could also do this using regex.

I added this because someone managed to accuse me of not doing anything.  I did not include it because it didn't work and I didn't see the point of adding something that is hopeless.

So here is what I have thus far, but as I said, it does not work:

var svarname = $(this).attr('id'.replace('^([\d+][(\w*)])', '');

The regex expression matches the parameter name, but adding ^ does nothing.

Comment: You had one problem, you decided to use regex and now you have two problems.

Comment: Well, if you have tried everything, then its not possible is it?  Or perhaps you haven't tried everything after all. Going by the evidence presented in your question, you have tried nothing.  Next time make sure to include what you have tried in your question, it is expected that all questions must include your own attempt to fix the problem.

Comment: Im not sure what this `instr` is you speak of?

Comment: In other words, what I'd like to do is replace the '[n][...]' with empty.  The fact is I have not been able to figure out how to use regex to replace the opposite of what I've matched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you failed to provide any of your working as @JK mentioned, You will not find an answer that you expect but since i understood part of your question, I will reply on that.

I will assume that you have an `input` element and an empty `p` tag

```
<input name='[n][somevariablename]'>

<p></p>
```

You are willing to use regex to parse out the **somevariablename** and store it in a variable

I've used jQuery in this case to achieve what you might have tried or not.

```
var source = $('input').attr('name');
var regex = /\[(\w+)\]\[(\w+)\]/;
var match = source.match(regex);

var yournewvariable = match[2];

$('p').html(yournewvariable);
```

[Live Example](http://jsfiddle.net/38y3yq7L/) - Your result will be in the empty `p` tag we created earlier.

---

*I hope next time you will include a proper question and upload your work in the question to narrow down the problem*

Comment: Hi. NMindz.  Yes, that's exactly what I was looking for. I knew match was in .net, but didn't see it in jquery.  It must be a part of javascript...

Comment: Sorry, I don't read the fine print enough.  This was my first question.  As you can see, I did upload what I had done, but I was missing the 'match' part.  Thanks so much for the help!